# Symfony RabbitMQ: run many consumers in console

Tags: php, symfony, rabbitmq

I think I have simple question but I can't answer on it:
**How can I run many consumers at once?**
For example I have 3 consumers

```
consumers:
    rename_image_folder: ...
    update_customer: ...
    create_protocol: ...
```

and how can I run them at once? I have to open 3 console window and run them? But in our project we have 10 microservice api and each one have at least one consumer. How can I work with it?

I believe that I that we have a way how to make it. For example, I have different **routing_key**, and I have to write different methods (or services) to processing queues. Maybe there is another way to processing it.

It will be very good if you apply an example please. Thanks!

Comment: The message bus could be a good choice for MOA, when you want to build an async communications. Here's an article on how you can connect different PHP apps https://blog.forma-pro.com/message-bus-to-every-php-application-42a7d3fbb30b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a bundle like [this one](https://github.com/Phobetor/rabbitmq-supervisor-bundle) and install supervisord on your server. The bundle will handle creating supervisord profiles from your rabbitmq settings, keeping your different consumers alive automatically.
I've got it working very stably with this bundle and `php-amqplib/rabbitmq-bundle`

Answer (score 2):

Different consumer would say different php process, this mean that you can scale up increasing the number of consumer adding more php process that consume message of the queue.

I suggest you to use a tool like Supervisord in order to control the number of php process and take care of the status of the process.

As example, you could configure a simple [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/index.html) process with the number of php process (the `numprocs` element):

```
[supervisord]
logfile = /tmp/supervisord.log
logfile_maxbytes = 10MB
directory = %(here)s
pidfile = /tmp/supervisord.pid
[program:todo]
command = php /var/www/symfony/bin/console rabbitmq:consumer -w sync
autostart = true
autorestart = true
numproc=5
```

Hope this help

Comment: A process per queue is not good all the time. It has downsides. If you 100 queues you need 100 processes to at least serve them all. A typical Symfony app needs 100Mb memory just to start so you need 10Gb memory

Comment: @MaksimKotlyar sure, but is a design issue: you can't consume from multiple queue

Comment: Actually, you can consume from multiple queues, though you have to reconfigure the application, and you cannot configure it at runtime. The solution is not that flexible. I like how EnqueueBundle does it. There are more options on how to deal with queues.

Comment: Hi @MaksimKotlyar thanks for share, i didn't know this!